# Set Volume mute to unmute on OrientationChange using setStreamMute() method of AudioManager is not working

Tags: android-audiomanager

Set Volume mute to unmute  on OrientationChange using setStreamMute() method of AudioManager is not working. 
Suppose i set Volume mute using setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true); by clicking on audButton in landscape mode. Then if i change Orientation & trying to set Volume unmute using setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false) in portrait mode then it is not working. I have allready debug my code, methods to set volume mute/unmute calling correctly.
I am using following given code by clicking on audButton -

```
audButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                //Log.v("Flip Camera", "Changing Camera Facing");
                audIsON = !audIsON;

                getAM().setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audIsON);

                if(audIsON == true)
                {
                    audButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speaker_volum_icon_mute);
                }
                else
                {
                    audButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speaker_volum_icon);
                }
                                //((SurveillanceApplication)getApplication()).setMute(audIsON);

            }
        });
```

---

Thanks in advance :)